# How to use ci.yml to declare env variables to be used in python?

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

-in gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  SECRET_KEY: secret_key
  DB_NAME: somedb_name
  DB_USER: postgres
  DB_HOST: mdillon-postgis
  DB_PORT: 5432
  DB_PASSWORD: ''
```

-in django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Django doesn't seem to pick up the variables declared on CI when running pipeline. How do I properly declare the env variables on testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone having the same confusion. Here are the steps:

1. Go to Settings > CI/CD > Variables. Add the variables and values:

```
  DB_NAME: your_db_name
  DB_USER: postgres
  DB_HOST: mdillon-postgis (or whatever service you are using)
  DB_PORT: 5432
  DB_PASSWORD: <leave it blank>
```

2. In gitlab-ci.yml

```
  POSTGRES_DB: $DB_NAME
  POSTGRES_USER: $DB_USER
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
  DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@mdillon__postgis:5432/$DB_NAME
```

3. In django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```